# Multiple Solutions when Fitting MA Model

Tags: time-series, moving-average

Given an MA(2) model

$$X_t = e_t + A_1 e_{t-1} + A_2 e_{t-2}$$

There are cases where there are multiple solutions. Given time series data that we can correctly estimate one solution $(A_1^*,A_2^*)$, how would we calculate the other pairs of coefficients satisfying the model from these?

How does this generalise?

Comment: What's an MA(2) model?

Comment: Moving average model, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average

Comment: For every $\theta_j$, $1/\theta_j$ will also work, won't it? But people usually restrict themselves to invertible models, which would restore uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks. Acronyms aren't always obvious. To me an MA model is a meta-analysis model. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-analysis